# Fixed Menu and problems with div

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm finally making my very first Wordpress Theme but yet I have some problems I have to solve. My blog has a fixed top menu, and right under it there's a div. I had to make that div `margin-top:55px` because of the menu (It was all over the div and you couldn't see anything of it). Everything was ok but there's a problem.

You know when you log in into your wordpress account, a 'menu options' bar appears at the top of the blog. Well, because of that bar, the div with `margin-top:55px` was more below than normal. What can I do to fix this? Here you have the codes.

```
#menu {
    height:55px;
    background-color: #000;
    width:100%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:101;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    position:fixed;
}

#underheader {
    margin-top:55px;
    color:#fff;
    width: 100%;
    height:15px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    padding-top:15px;
}
```

[Here's the link to my website in case you need it.](http://danithemes.fanscity.eu/shugar) Log in to your Wordpress account to see the changes.

I'm sorry if I wrote something wrong. I speak Spanish.

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing the height of the image and or also try using different image to make sure everything go well. Had the same issue in my blog also.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find in `style.css` `#top-navigation` then add `display:none` before the closing } or hack away to try remove the html.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use JQuery, check if '#wpadminbar' exist, if true add 'wpadminbar_on' class to the 'body':

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('#wpadminbar').length){
        $('body').addClass('wpadminbar_on');
    }
});
```

now add the CSS, if '#wpadminbar' exist, '#menu' and '#underheader' will get the next:

```
.wpadminbar_on #menu
{
    margin-top: 32px;
}

.wpadminbar_on #underheader
{
    margin-top: 87px;
}
```

*notice the 'px' value, i made it for this situation, if you are going to change the '#menu' or '#wpadminbar' height for example, you will need to update the values.